Confused about the proof of Ramsey theorem
The $R(s,t)$ is defined as the smallest $N$ such that every two edge color of $K_N$, we either have a monochromatic $K_s$ or $K_t$.
To prove $R(s,t)$ exists and is finite, The theorem goes as

The following inequality holds:
$$ \forall s,t \geq 2, R(s,t)\le R(s-1,t)+R(s,t-1). $$

I know the way to prove it but got stuck on some details. Suppose we color $K_{R(s-1,t)+R(s,t-1)}$ with any two colors, then pick a vertex $v$ and let $A$ be the set of vertices that connect $v$ with color $1$ and $B$ be the set connects $v$ with color $2$, then WLOG, $|A| \geq R(s-1,t)$,  we know it either have a monochromatic $K_t$ (We are done) or a monochromatic $K_{s-1}$, the idea is adding $v$, we have a monochromatic $K_s$, howver if I am very unlucky and the $K_{s-1}$ is of color $2$. How can I proceed? I know the color does not matter here but can not convince myself.

$|A| \ge R(s-1, t)$ implies that there is either a $K_{s-1}$ of color 1 or a $K_t$ of color 2. Separately, it also implies there is a $K_{s-1}$ of color 2 or a $K_t$ of color 1, but you don't need this.

Could you please elaborate a bit? I am still confused.

It might help if you read only the first sentence of @angryavian's comment. The point is that your "very unlucky" situation  cannot arise.

I still do not understand. I do not give the definition of $R(s,t)$ as the minimum integer $N$, such that for every two colors, we either have a $K_s$ of color 1 or $K_t$ of color 2.

I think that is the source of your confusion: your statement of the definition of $R(s, t)$ is not right. It should be specifically "either a $K_s$ of one color, or a $K_t$ of the other color." See here or here.

So mine is weaker than those you quoted?

Kind of. Your definition only cares about $\min{s, t}$, in the sense that $R(s, t) = R(s', t')$ whenever $\min{s, t}$ = \min{s', t'}$, so having two parameters is unnecessary.
